# Stop reduce_while with tuple

Tags: elixir

I want to stop reduce_while when my function get {:error,reason} instead of false

my code is:

```
Enum.reduce_while(
      [1,2,3,4],
      0,
      fn filename, _foo ->
        if carica() do
          IO.puts "OK"
          {:cont, carica()}
        else
          IO.puts "KO"
          {:halt, carica()}
        end
      end
    )

  def carica() do
    {:error,"ERROR!!!!!"}
  end
```

I want a output like

```
"KO"
{:error,"ERROR"}
```

because in this way I have

```
OK
OK
OK
OK
{:error, "ERROR!!!!!"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pattern match the response from your function, use `case`:

```
case response = carica() do
  {:error, reason} ->
    IO.puts "KO"
    {:halt, response}
  _ ->
    IO.puts "OK"
    {:cont, response}
end
```